# Structure: Consecutive Clauses

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, sentence-structure

A question about the sentence structure of [this](http://www.mercurynews.com/science/ci_26529196/conflicts-yosemite-bears-fall-dramatically-people-bears-learn):

> In 1997, black bears broke into more than 600 cars in the park, ***searching for*** human food as they tore open the doors of Toyotas and Hondas, ***smashing minivan*** windows with their paws.

Could it be that an "*and*" is missing between the "searching for..." clause and "smashing minivan..." clause?

Comment: No. This is [*asyndeton*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asyndeton), a common method of coordination.

Comment: @StoneyB But would adding "and" have made the sentence more readable?

Comment: Not to me it wouldn't.

Comment: @StoneyB So, I could write "I have a cat a dog" instead of "I have a cat **and** a dog"?

Comment: Did you read what StoneyB provided you with? The link explains it and ***no***, you cannot write *'I've a cat a dog.'*

Answer (score 1):

As StoneyB has mentioned, this is called asyndeton. It is used because placing an "and" between the clauses would slow down the "reading pace" of the sentence. The author wishes to emphasize the ferocity of the bears. You generally will want to avoid using asyndeton unless you have a strong reason.